# Read a file into a string in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, file, error-handling, console

I am trying to read a file into a string which then I will send to another application.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace FileApplication
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                // Create an instance of StreamReader to read from a file.
                // The using statement also closes the StreamReader.
                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("c:\text.txt"))
                {
                    string line;

                    // Read and display lines from the file until 
                    // the end of the file is reached. 
                    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(line);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

                // Let the user know what went wrong.
                Console.WriteLine("The file could not be read:");
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting the error:

```
The file could not be read:
Could not find file 'c:\users\andymarkmn\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\FileApplication\FileApplication\bin\Debug\text.txt'.
```

I have tried putting the file in bin debug folders as well.

How to make sure the code works ?

**EDIT:  As suggested, I tried using the different ways.**

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace FileApplication
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string filepath = "c:\\text.txt";

            try
            {
                string lines = File.ReadAllText(filepath);
                Console.Write(lines);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

                // Let the user know what went wrong.
                Console.WriteLine("The file could not be read:");
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

I still get the error:

```
The file could not be read:
Could not find file 'c:\text.txt'.
```

Comment: Doesn't help with the problem, but `File.ReadAllLines` would be easier

Comment: Th error message has different filename than the one you were trying to read.

Comment: @stuartd Hi, could you give a code sample as well. I am new to c# and .net stack.

Comment: do you have this file `c:\text.txt`

Comment: `string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(filePath)` - [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1(v=vs.110).aspx), or `File.ReadAllText` if you just want the text as one big string

Comment: @AshleyJohn sorry, I copied the error one from a different run of the program using different file.

Comment: For testing just try `using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("text.txt"))` . Keep the file in the Debug\bin folder

Comment: what does it say when you first check if the file exists File.Exists(file)? Run visual studio as administrator and see if that works.. if yes it`s just a ACL problem.

Comment: Your problem is probably caused by your attempt to write to the root folder.  That folder is restricted so Windows is most likely redirecting to your VirtualStore folder which is located here:  C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\VirtualStore.  Try putting your file there or choosing a different folder.

Answer (score 4):

You have accidentally used an unwanted escape sequence in your filename string.

```
new StreamReader("c:\text.txt")
```

should be

```
new StreamReader(@"c:\text.txt")
```

Otherwise `\` gets treated as an escape character, at `\t` is a tab character. This leaves an unexpected result, and the wrong path for the file.

`@` instructs the compiler to ignore any escape characters in the string.

Comment: I tried using "c:\\text.txt" . I get the same error.

Comment: Are you sure you're running that version? Add a Console.WriteLine on the filePath variable so you can be sure that it's picked up your changes.

Comment: Console.WriteLine(filepath) gives c:\text.txt  That is not correct right?

Comment: Yes, it is correct. The final string should look like `c:\test.txt` Are you running your visual studio / application as admin? Maybe it's denying you rights to the root of C.

Answer (score 0):

`"c:\text.txt"` will not work as `\` is an escape character.

use `@"c:\text.txt"` or `"c:\\text.txt"`

Comment: The error is suggesting the file does not exist (or you do not have permissions to know of its existence)

Answer (score 0):

When `StreamReader` is given a non-qualified path as a parameter, it will look for the file in the application's working directory as you have done:

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("c:\text.txt"))
```

If the file isn't located there, probably you should give `StreamReader` a fully qualified path:

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"c:\text.txt"))
//or...
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("c:\\text.txt"))
```

Comment: or Run your Visual Studio using Admin rights...maybe that'll work.

Comment: I put it in d, still the same error. The filepath variable reads only one \ ?

Comment: @AndyMarkman then try running the Application using **Admin Rights** ... further see to it that if there are any typo in the `filepath` or `filename`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"C:\text.txt"))
```

If you use `c:\text`, C# considers that the string has a tabulador between `C:` and `text.txt`.